# Default "Preview On" - Illustrator plugins and effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

Every time I use an effect or a modifying function ("Extrude and Bevel" or "Split into grid" for example) I have to check "Preview". I always want preview to be enabled.

**Is there a way to get Illustrator to have preview enabled by default?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Note, the **Spacebar** will toggle the preview option in *some* dialog windows. (specifically, those without any input fields)

Comment: Ok, darn it. Space will often just add a space into the the input field that is selected in the dialog.

Comment: ... that's why I posted "*some*".

Comment: That's why I posted "will often" :) Thanks for the answer. I hope Adobe changes this in the future!

Answer (score -3):

use tab to move focus to the checkmark

Comment: Please explain better what you mean, for example add a screenshot ...

Comment: It works - but it's just as annoying to have to do that every time as it is to click it with the mouse cursor :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.